# Как удалить повторяющиеся элементы из массива, при этом сохранить его последовательность в Java?

Tags: java

Дан массив строк. Необходимо удалить из него все дубли, а оставшиеся строки объединить в одну в порядке следования в массиве.

Т.е. если есть массив:
[ "aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "dd"]

то в результате получится:
[ "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]

Comment: Про множества знаете?

Comment: "а оставшиеся строки объединить в одну в порядке следования в массиве." - так какой результат в итоге должен получиться? Массив [ "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"] или строка "aabbccdd"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная задача состоит в том, чтобы *преобразовать* входной массив строк в *одну* строку, в которой не будет дубликатов, что достаточно просто реализовать при помощи Stream API, в частности `Stream::distinct` для фильтрации дубликатов и `Collectors.joining` для получения строки результата:

```java
public static String keepDistinct(String ... arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]")); // в виде "[a, b, c]"
//      .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")); // с разделителем ", " - в виде "a, b"
//      .collect(Collectors.joining()); // без разделителя, в виде "ab"
}
```

```java
System.out.println(keepDistinct("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "dd"));
// -> [aa, bb, cc, dd]
```

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedHashSet` - для удаления дубликатов с сохранением порядка добавления.
`StringJoiner` - для формирования итоговой строки.

```
String oneStringWithoutDuplicates(String[] strings) {

    var joiner = new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]");
    new LinkedHashSet<>(List.of(strings))
            .forEach(s -> joiner.add("\"" + s + "\""));
            
    return joiner.toString();
    
}
```